# How can I pass results of CSS media query to JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I have a JS variable controlling styling of the page. I want it to change depending on screen resolution. How can I make it depend on results of CSS media query.

I know that I can check screen resolution directly in JS but I want to keep all styling decisions within CSS rather than spread it across JS and CSS files.

to avoid XY problem: I am using Leaflet and JS variable decides whatever map control panel listing available layers is collapsed or not. It should be collapsed on small screens (mobile) and not collapsed on large screens (proper monitors).

The relevant code is available below

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #map {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--based on https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/ example -->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
  <script>
    var positron = L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '#{openstreetmap_copyright_notice}, basemap: &copy; <a href=\"http://cartodb.com/attributions\">CartoDB</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 19
      }),
      osmcarto = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      });

    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [39.73, -104.99],
      zoom: 10,
      layers: [positron]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
      "positron": positron,
      "osm-carto": osmcarto
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, {}, {
      collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map); //false/true should be specified by CSS
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have been using this as a way to test for mobile browsers in javascript: `if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )`

Comment: To quote part of the question: `I know that I can check screen resolution directly in JS but I want to keep all styling decisions within CSS rather than spread it across JS and CSS files.`

Comment: Setting a js variable has nothing to do with css. Can use [window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) though

Comment: @charlietfl So it is impossible to make JS variable to depend on anything set by CSS?

Comment: Not impossible but would be more complex since you would have to check a style property of something using js and that style would be set based on viewport anyway

Comment: Personally it sounds like you are over thinking this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty cheezy solution, but it would mean not hardcoding any width properties in JS.

Add a dummy, invisible element to the page.

```
<div id="dummy"></div>

#dummy::after {
  display: none;
  content: 'false';
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #dummy::after {
    content: 'true';
  }
}
```

Then read the value of the `content` in JS:

```
var isBigScreen = window.getComputedStyle(
    document.querySelector('#dummy'), ':after'
).getPropertyValue('content');
```

`isBigScreen` will be either `"true"` or `"false"`.  You might want to add some code to recheck that if the screen size changes.

```
if(isCollapsed === '"false"') {
    isCollapsed = false;
} else {
    isCollapsed = true;
}
```

may be used to convert it to a standard boolean.

Comment: "isBigScreen will be either true or false" Are you sure? For me at least on Firefox 61.0.1 I get `"true"` or `"false"`. Even more curiously, both `isBigScreen==="true"` and `isBigScreen==true` and `isBigScreen==="false"` and `isBigScreen==false` return false.

Comment: That's genuinely bizarre...`isBigScreen == '"true"'` evaluates to true though.  `getPropertyValue` is including double quotation marks `"` in the string.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I added a clarification that string is returned with quotes and idea how it may be handled.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to do this, either as a one-off check or (more usefully) with a callback (more on the callback option [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries)):

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)").addListener(function(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        // The window currently matches the query
    } else {
        // It doesn't
    }
});
```

To avoid repeating the query text in the JavaScript, you can search through `document.styleSheets` and using their `media` property. May not be a lot of fun, but I can't imagine any other way to avoid duplicating the media query.

For example, this uses the first `screen and` rule it finds ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLmj7h6n/)):

```
// Find the rule
const rule = Array.from(document.styleSheets).reduce((found, sheet) => {
    return found || Array.from(sheet.cssRules || sheet.rules).find(rule => {
        return rule.conditionText && rule.conditionText.startsWith("screen and ");
    });
}, null);
if (rule) {
    const query = rule.conditionText.substring(11);
    console.log("rule found, setting listener for: " + query);
    window.matchMedia(query).addListener(function(e) {
        console.log("matches? ", e.matches);
    });
} else {
    console.log("No rule found");
}
```

Naturally, you'd need to wait for any stylesheets loaded via `link` elements to be loaded first.

Comment: To quote part of the question: `I know that I can check screen resolution directly in JS but I want to keep all styling decisions within CSS rather than spread it across JS and CSS files.`

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny - You can search through the stylesheets; updated. Won't be pretty, but should be possible.

Comment: @MateuszKonieczny - Added an example of that.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I could think of is by setting a certain style in your CSS and then checking for that style in Javascript.

e.g. something like `document.getElementById('map').style.width === '1000px'`

Comment: This still goes back to that dimension being window dimension dependent so might as well just use js to check directly and logic will be simpler to follow

Comment: @charlietfl As far as I understand the answer it suggests doing something like `@media (...) { #map { width: 1000px } }` and then performing the above test. (Where the RHS should be `'1000px'`, of course.)

Comment: @idmean thanks for spotting that, updated my answer.